# Usage of the phrase fall back

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, synonyms

I came across the usage of "falling back" in a poem (Ted Hughes' *Crow and Mama*), and googled for its meaning and its usages. 
Putting the poem aside, what I'd like to understand is when an english speaker would use this phrase, and when would he use the other synonyms such as retreat, withdraw, and recoil.

Comment: The Huns are attacking!  Fall back!!

Comment: And it should be noted that "fall back", as an adjective or a verb, is used in various technical disciplines to refer to the act and facilities related to providing emergency services in the event of some sort of critical equipment failure.  About a week ago the lack of adequate fall-back facilities caused British Airways flights out of two London airports to be cancelled for several days, after the primary computers crashed.

Comment: [fall back](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-back): (literary) to move back suddenly from someone or something, often because you are frightened: *She fell back in horror/disgust.*

Comment: 'When he burst out in rage / She fell back with an awful gash..., I think this simply indicates a fall and its direction. The gash suggests that his burst of rage injured her and knocked her off balance.

Comment: @Spagirl, well, I gave it a deep thought, and seeing this line in the poem context, I interpret this "falling back" as her (Mama) withdrawing from the battle depicted in this paragraph, and coming back at him on the next one (*When he stopped she closed on him*). Generally speaking, the whole poem depicts a continuing-battle between Crow and his Mom.

Comment: Can you add the relevant portion of the poem to the question? It's hard to know what it means out of context.

Comment: @Barmar, as I mentioned, I'm less interested with its meaning within the poem context. Rather, I'd like an explanation about its general usage, with regard to its alternatives.

Comment: @O.d There are a number of different meanings depending on the context. A good dictionary should answer that.